# Eliminating x = 0 from an equation when x can be equal to all real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have the equation:

$$2+0x=a+0x$$
The solution to this equation for $x$ is all real numbers. If I then multiply each side by $x$ I get:
$$2x=ax$$
The solution to this equation for $x$ is still all real numbers. If I wanted to divide each side by $x$, I would have to assume that $x$ is not equal to $0$. So if I do that:
$$2=a$$
which is also equal to $$2+0x=a+0x$$ which has $x =$ all real numbers. But since I divided by $x$ didn't I remove $x = 0$ from the solutions of $x$? But $x = 0$ still works in the last equation?

Comment: You can only multiply each side of an equation by a non-zero number, so you are already excluding $x=0$ when you do it in the second step.

Comment: Why can't we multiply each side of an equation by a zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide by $x$, you say

if $x \ne 0$, then $2 = a$; which is true (here, we are not even considering the case where $x=0$).

But in your case, even if $x=0$, then also $2 = a$; because before multiplying by $x$, we already knew that $a=2$.

Comment: If we just had the equation 2ax = 2x, and x = 0, a would be equal to all real numbers right? How would we then say what the value of a is? If x = 0, then a = all real numbers, but if x is not equal to 0 then a = 2. Do we just say that a = 2 to get all cases of x?

Comment: 2ax = 2x can be written as 2*x*(a-1) = 0; Now the last equation is satisfied if and only if "x = 0 OR a = 1". I hope you understand what 'OR' means (if not let me know).

Comment: Does the "or" include the fact that x or a could be equal to all real numbers? If x was 0, a could be all real numbers for example. Or if a = 1, x could be all real numbers. Does the "or" say that the other variable could be anything? For example, if x = 0, a could be anything. 

Also, if we had to solve for a what would we say? Would we say that a = 1? Or would we say that a = all real numbers?

Comment: If x is 0, then ofcourse a could be all real numbers; otherwise I would have specified what values of a are possible. Also, it is very obvious that if x = 0, then the eqn would satisfy no matter what value of a is chosen. Similarly, when a = 1, x could be any real number.

Comment: If we were to specify what values of a are possible, we would say a =1 or a = all real numbers right? Or would it be correct to say that a = 1 to cover all cases?

Comment: Also, if you have to answer what are the possibles values of a? Then you would say if x is 0, then a could be any real number, otherwise a is 1

Comment: See if your question is such that you want to satisfy the equation no matter what values x can take, then you would say a is 1